# Logcat is only show level tag

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, logcat

I was installing Eclipse on ubuntu 14.04.

However, the only thing shown on logcat is just "level".

[image]

I had tried to use console to open adb log, that is,

```
./adb logcat
```

and it would show all of the message.

Does anyone can tell me how to show all kinds of the message on Eclipse logcat?

Comment: I am facing same problem....how did you solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had find out how to solve this problem.

Open the file

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs
```

and paste the following setting.

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=176
logcat.view.colsize.Level=154
logcat.view.colsize.PID=154
logcat.view.colsize.TID=65
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=179
logcat.view.colsize.Text=863
logcat.view.colsize.Time=133
```

It works for me.

Comment: if you using ios or linux .metadata will be hide just use ctrl+h it will show the hide folders